# Oracle Query execution vs Foreach loop in c#

Tags: c#, oracle, foreach

Which of the following approaches is better?

- Oracle query execution(which takes 6 seconds to complete in TOAD)
- Looping through the Data table containing 100 records in C#

Comment: If the query execution takes 6 seconds, I have little doubt that the looping will be faster but **why** is the query taking 6 seconds?

Comment: Query involves in multiple table joining

Comment: Thanks Lieven... Your suggestion works fine in my case.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I was trying to say. Wether a query or looping will be faster depends for a large part on the ammount of data to be handled and the way it is handled. I can come up with scenario's where looping will be faster but likewise, it's not difficult to come up with scenario's where a query will be faster.

Comment: No.. My actual requirement is - I had to execute 2 queries (which are almost the same except 2 conditions) to populate 2 result sets. Then I thought I can execute the query only once and loop through the result to get the first result set. So,I asked the question like which is better( executing the query for the second time or loop thro' the result set)

Comment: Post your "actual" requirement and we can then solve it. If you don't, how can we help you?

Answer (score 0):

usually the Database can better optimize the query, which makes it faster than looping in C#

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data in C# it would sugest that you've executed a DB query to fetch that data first.

So:

```
Execute DB query
Sending results to application
Loop over the data.
```

If you did it all in a query in the DB:

```
Execute DB query
Send results
```

It would seem logically that the second option would involve less work. You could also try to better optimise your original DB query to reduce the fetch time.

Hope it helps...